# List<T>.Find method in Metro apps

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm wondering why `List<T>.Find` is not available when creating a Metro application in C#. It's still in .NET Framework 4.5 (Windows Forms, WPF) but not in Metro style applications. Is there an alternative or is there just not going to be a find method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its a choice MSFT made. Just use Linq's `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`.

It surely sounds like they are doing a lot of cleanup...